# How to use ajax response list as struts2 iterator value?

Tags: ajax, struts2

I am using following ajax function :

```
 $.ajax({
       url: "userhomeonload",
       contentType: 'application/json',
       type: 'POST',
      datatype:'json', 
       async: true,
       success: function (res) {
                 alert(res[i].name+" "+res[i].rollNo);
    }  });
```

I am getting correct result in alert box.
Now I want to use the list returned by this ajax in struts iterator as follows :

```
<s:iterator value="list">
   <div>
     <s:property value='name'></s:property>
     <s:property value="rollNo"></s:property>
   </div>
</s:iterator>
```

But nothing is getting displayed on screen. Can anyone tell me how can I do so?

Comment: return a JSP, not a JSON, and iterate there.

Comment: Or use js to add elements.

Comment: @Andrea Ligios ,I don't get your point.Please explain what are you saying.Also how can I do so?

Comment: When you perform an AJAX call in Struts2, the two main type of results that are usually returned are: 1) **JSON** - preferred, newer, smaller, and handy. You can't use struts tags on the object, you need to manipulate it, or iterate it, with JavaScript; 2) **JSP** - a JSP snippet (only your iterator for example, and the declaration of the struts-tags taglib), and apply it to an element in your page, for example a div. That way, you can use struts tags on the result before it is applied to the page. Got it ? :)

Comment: How can I implement your 2nd option?

Comment: @AndreaLigios please explain 2nd type of result i.e. JSP snippet.I don't know how to use JSP snippet as ajax response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @AndreaLigios please explain 2nd type of result i.e. JSP snippet.I don't know how to use JSP snippet as ajax response.

Main.jsp (complete)

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="struts-tags.tld" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            $(function(){   
                $('#loader').on("keypress click", function(e) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "<s:url action='ajaxAction'/>",
                    }).done(function(result) {
                        $("#target").html(result);
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>   
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="loader" />
        <div id="target"></div>
    <body>
</html>
```

Struts.xml (relevant)

```
<action name="ajaxAction" class="foo.bar.AjaxAction">
    <result>Snippet.jsp</result>
</action>
```

AjaxAction (relevant)

```
private String testString;
/* Getter and Setter */

public String execute(){
   testString = "I'm loaded with AJAX";
   return SUCCESS;
}
```

Snippet.jsp (complete)

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="struts-tags.tld" %>

<!-- This is the result page. You can use Struts tags here, 
the generated HTML will be appended to the target div. -->

TestString: <s:property value="testString" />
```

Output:

```
<body>
    <input type="button" id="loader" />
    <div id="target">TestString: I'm loaded with AJAX</div>
<body>
```

Comment: This is working.I want to ask 1 more question.The content in my Snippet.jsp is to be included inside a showcase.Now the showcase plugin is not working in Main.jsp.Can you suggest me any solution

Comment: Glad that helped. I've no idea of what a showcase plugin is or why it is not working (anymore?). But this sounds like a totally new question, so I suggest you to open a new, well described question to get better help

Comment: I am just getting "success" instead of "my message" as response for my ajax request. my code looks almost same as above.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what is happening behind the scene is after your ajax call you are only getting the JSON object but the the value of "list"

```
<s:iterator value="list">
```

is not mapped by the OGNL from the valuestack to the result page , for this approach to work in your case you have to set the property using JS.

As Andrea correctly explained if you return your result as a JSP all the property of your action object will be mapped by OGNL to the respective UI tags.