# How to to use Struts 2 tags in jQuery as String

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, struts2

I'm not able to use Struts 2 tags in jQuery as `String`.

**This is my `div`:**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
            <label>Expensed Type</label>
            <s:select name="expenseList[0].param" 
                      list="'advertisement','food'"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
            <label>Amount</label>
            <s:textfield name="expenseList[0].value" value="%{expenseList[0].value}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
            <label>Date</label>
            <s:textfield name="expenseList[0].dt" value="%{expenseList[0].dt}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="col-xs-4 right">
    <span class="glyphicon-plus"></span>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </div>
```

I would like to use above as `String` in JavaScript, so that whenever a user clicks on `add` button It must generate a new row. I am adding above to a jQuery click event

**As below:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).on('click', '#add', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $(".row").append("< /div  <div class=\"row\">"
                    + "<div class = \"form - group col - xs - 12 col - sm - 6 col - lg - 3\">"
                    + "<label> Expensed Type </label>"
                    + "<s:select name=\"expenseList[1].param\" list=\"'advertisement','food'\"/>"
                    + "</div>"
                    + "<div class = \"form - group col - xs - 12 col - sm - 6 col - lg - 3\">"
                    + "<label> Amount </label>"
                    + "<s:textfield name=\"expenseList[1].value\" value=\"%{expenseList[1].value}\"/>"
                    + "</div>"
                    + "  <div class = \"form - group col - xs - 12 col - sm - 6 col - lg - 3\">"
                    + "<label> Date </label>"
                    + "<s:textfield name=\"expenseList[1].dt\" value=\"%{expenseList[1].dt}\"/>\"/> "
                    + "</div>"
                    + "</div>"
                    );
        });
    });
    </script>
```

**It is showing following exception:**

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /pages/expense/AddExpense.jsp (line: 88, column: 43) quote symbol expected
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:443)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:89)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttribute(Parser.java:222)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttributes(Parser.java:162)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttributes(Parser.java:153)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1236)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1452)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)



Line 88 is `+ "<s:select name=\"expenseList[1].param\" list=\"'advertisement','food'\"/>"`
```

Comment: What does `expenseList` contain?

Comment: expenseList is arrayList. That will store many instances of Expense object

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Struts tags that generate HTML in the javascript variable as string, because the generated code should *escape* quotes.

javascript string requires *quotes* around the content and every quote inside the content should be escaped, so it doesn't end a string content.

You can also try with single or double quotes to delimit a string value, but without properly escaping it will fail before it's rendered.

Instead of generating HTML from the Struts tags in javascript variable use Ajax to load HTML returned as Ajax response.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using javascript only to append HTML (and not to manipulate it nor the DOM), consider returning a JSP snippet instead.

You can find the the [complete example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24181930/1654265).

Also remember to map `keypress` too, or users using keyboard won't fire the event.

It would be something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#add").on('keypress click', function(event) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "<s:url action='loadNewRowTemplateWithAjaxAction'/>",
            }).done(function(result) {
                $(".row").append(result);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This let you keep a clean JSP and perform operations server-side, like checking if it's possible to add a new row, or updating a row counter in session, and so on...